# How to use "for" with __VA_ARGS__ in macros?

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-functions

I've written a macro like this for my project:

```
#define CLICK_IF_VISIBLE(string,...) \
    for (auto iterator in __VA_ARGS__)\
    {\
        Handle(iterator); \
    }
```

I need to handle each individual string in the arg list instead of all the list (because the function Handle does take a list of strings as argument and I cannot do anything about it). But as you can guess, the compiler returns errors at the "for" function.
What did I do wrong? How can I use "for" and "in" to deal with "**VA_ARGS**" as a list of strings?
Thank you.

Comment: any reason use macro here?

Comment: maybe use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack ?

Comment: there is no `in` in c++

Comment: @gkhaos You're right, C++ uses ":", I feel so stupid now.

Comment: @appleapple Yeah, my boss asked me to. :/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a macro for this. Write a function template.

```
template <typename... Strings>
void click_if_visible(Strings... strings)
{
    for (auto iterator : { strings... })
    {
         Handle(iterator);
    }
}
```